# Voltage at the load in matched transmission line

Tags: voltage-divider, transmission-line

We have a source (Z_s) and load (Z_load) connected with a transmission line. It is known that the connection is matched, that means Z_s=Z_0 and Z_0=Z_load. If the voltage from source is 1V, what will be the voltage on load?

It may look as a textbook exercise, but it's not. I'm having hard time understanding  what is going on if we place a matched transmission line between source and load. All the books I have focus on reflections and physical details, but not much about more simplistic real scenarios.

If the connection is matched as described can the transmission line be ignored (considering it's loseless) and voltage on load be calculated from standard voltage divider? Thus, getting 0.5V on load, or do we need to consider the line also and it's 1/3V on load?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Z_s` is the internal resistance of the source. So you will see `1V` after this resistance, at the output of the source. Knowing this, you can omit the `Z_s` in your calculations. Now it's just a matter of calculating the voltage divider and since `Z_o`=`Z_load`, `V_load` will be half of the source voltage. Thus `V_load` = `0.5V`

Comment: And if we put another Z_s1 after the source, which is also matched (Z_s1=Z_o), then all the parts in line will have 1/3 of the source voltage?

Comment: Yes. However, one will add `Z_s1` tot `Z_o` to make it easier. So the line resistance will now be twice as much as the load resistance. So `V_load = V_s / 3` indeed